# activate another conda env inside python code

Tags: python, conda

I need to use both python2.7 and python3.6 for a task. I used conda to create two python envs. I know how to use a shell script to control the code running and switch between different envs. Say I need to run python2.7 code first, then I run python 3.6. My question is could I first run python 2.7 code, and then in the python 2.7 code, I directly activate the python3.6 conda env, and run the python 3.6 code?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Why don't you just (back-)port the code?

Comment: Because some dependency only has python2.x version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your task maybe it is enough to change the environment just calling the shell from python using:

```
your python 2.7 code

os.system("Command to change your kernel")  

your python 3.6 code
```

Maybe you need to add some extra code to take the outputs or new inputs if there are
and continue running the code.

If that doesn't work maybe is easier to call the python 3.6 function direct from the command:

```
os.system("python3 '/function36.py' ")
```

Or also using the function [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) from your 2.7 code:

```
return_code = subprocess.call("python3 '/function36.py'", shell=True)
```

Using Python 3.6 you can also use the subprocess.run()