# Can I activate another conda env inside python code?

Tags: python, pytorch, subprocess, conda, python-venv

It is copy [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430434/activate-another-conda-env-inside-python-code)  because the previous answer wasn’t appropriate for me. The situation is that I have to use different  [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#conda-1) versions in my code for some recognitions. So while talking with GPT, I assembled this code.

```
import os
import subprocess

def get_env_list():
    envs = []
    output = subprocess.check_output(['conda', 'env', 'list'])
    for line in output.splitlines():
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        if line.startswith('#') or not line:
            continue
        env = line.split()[0]
        envs.append(env)
    return envs

def set_environment(env_name, valid_envs=get_env_list()):
    if env_name in valid_envs:
        os.system(F'conda activate {env_name}')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid environment name')
   
def get_current_env():
    env = os.environ.get('CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV')
    if env is None:
        return 'base'
    else:
        return env

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_env_list())
    print(get_current_env())

    d = {1 : 1}
    print(d)

    set_environment('AMZ')
    print(get_current_env())
    print(d)
```

But it is not work.
The output is

```
['base', 'AMZ', 'Amazon', 'lilit', 'lilit_clone', 'sCool']
lilit_clone
{1: 1}
lilit_clone
{1: 1}
```

I've started in `lilit_clone` env and still in it.
So - how to resolve my situation?

Comment: I feel that this might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why specifically do you want to use two (or more) versions of PyTorch? Going further even if you do need to use two different versions of the package can it be two separate programs instead of one?

Comment: I have descktop app with GUI and so on. I have to split audio by voices and after that determine languages. But I cant use cloud solutions. all have to be offline

so it is not 2 programs bc one GUI.
Or I have to pikle and use subprocesses only?
Are there anoother ways?

Comment: You still didn't answer the first question, why do you need two versions of PyTorch? Also please [edit] your question to provide any clarification.

Comment: look the question asks - can I use 2 env in one python code.
It does not matter why I want it, is not it?
If it is impossible - just say it ))

Comment: As I said, have a look at [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are facing problem X and seem to think Y (using two different versions of PyTorch) is the solution. There might be another solution for problem X which is better than Y.

Comment: but now I wanna to receive mental joy from viewing the problem Y solution from python guru.  Is it enough? I am a python teacher and wanna to know more and more. But thanks for your open heart whishing to help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import/use two different versions of a library (pytorch) in one program in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63629212/how-can-i-import-use-two-different-versions-of-a-library-pytorch-in-one-progra) and before you say that your question is about using two different conda env's, no that is not possible either. An environment is a **completely separate interpreter**, running one program on two interpreters isn't possible.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thank a lot. I see. You are better then GPT ) It is th answer.